# backup mysql database without losing portability with java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

i am trying to add a "create backup" option on one of my desktop applications which i have developed by java. i have searched a lot about this and found some approaches to solve this problem, but all of them destroy a single important concept "portability" . many people suggest to use mysqldump.exe (in windows) to do this, but i guess i need to know the mysql installation folder in order to take this approach . the below is the recommended code which by the way failed to run properly (i dont know why, please tell me if you notice the reason)

```
private static String dbName = "shams";
private static String dbUserName = "root";
private static String dbPassword = "";

public static boolean backupDB(File file) {
    String path = file.getPath();
    if (!path.contains(".sql")) {
        file = new File(path +".sql");
    }

    String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUserName + " -p" + dbPassword + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + file.getPath();
    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {

        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
            runtimeProcess.destroy();
            return true;
        } else {

            System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
        }


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();


    }

    return false;
}
```

and some suggest to simply copy the database to a certain location.

so.. what should i do to this in a neat way? any third party jar available?

--edit ---

the problem with the given code is that, when you dont have a password for a user (in this case root user) you should not mention the password in your command. the command should be like this :    `String executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUserName +  " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + file.getPath();`

and also you don't need to specify the mysql installation folder after all. the above code works as it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "destroying portability"? What examples did you see, and how did they "destroy portability"?

Comment: i have mentioned the example code. as u  can see we need to know the installation folder of mysql to be able to exec the mysqldump command. "knowing the instalation folder" means loosing portability .

Comment: You could say that. (Or should I say "u cld say that"?). But if you run this against a 'personal' mysql server you do need to have that installed so it's only part of installation: make sure the installer checks for mysql and searches for / asks for the locations of the mysqldump command?

Comment: If you don't want to break "portability" then add a control where the user could set the location of **mysqldump** program (.exe, .o or another extensions, depending on OS). and execute it without problems. Remember, there are other [software characteristics](http://www.ianswer4u.com/2011/10/characteristics-of-good-software.html#axzz27D7ysfsa) beside portability and you must not break them just to "save" 1.

Comment: @luiggimendoza i may take that choice . but what other characteristics are in danger! in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pure Java solutions to this problem; e.g.

- http://code.google.com/p/java-sqldump/
- http://www.isocra.com/2004/10/dumptosql/

(I haven't checked either of these to see if they do a decent job ... YMMV.)

However, I'd be wary of using a 3rd-party dump program, because of the risk that you might end up with a dump that doesn't restore properly.

Yes, you do need to know the path to the `mysqldump` program.  But that can be dealt with using sensible defaults and/or an entry in a configuration file.  Your "destroying portability" comment is making a mountain out of a molehill.

---

I cannot see anything obviously wrong with your code.  I suggest that you capture the "standard error" and "standard output" from `mysqldump` and see what it says.

- Maybe it is something like incorrect credentials or a non-existent output directory.
- Maybe you got one of the options incorrect.  (Is that really how you are supposed to use the `-B` option??)

Comment: let me check them out. and nice saying "Your "destroying portability" comment is making a mountain our of a molehill." i enjoyed it.

Comment: a bout first recommend : This project currently has no downloads.

Answer (score 1):

First, needing to know the location of the mysqldump executable does not necessarily mean a loss of portability - just make it a configuration parameter - either as a command-line option to the program, or in a configuration file.

Second, your issue with running the mysqldump command is likely related to your use of Runtime.exec(). The ProcessBuilder object gives you much more control. There are many questions/answers here on SO and all over the web about the proper use of ProcessBuilder - you will likely find some of them useful.

As far as I know, there is no all-java way to perform a mysqldump without actually running the mysqldump executable.